# Upload Image from Drawable Folder Using OkHTTP3 Android

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartform-data, okhttp

I am using the below code (okhttp3) to create request body for uploading image to server

```
requestBody = new okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("picture", imageFileName,
                                    okhttp3.RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, imageFile))
                            .addFormDataPart("name", mFullName).build();
```

This code works fine when I take a picture from camera or gallery. Now my intent is to upload a picture from the **drawable** folder.

It would be great if I could create a **file** from the **drawable image**, so that I can simply pass the value through `imageFile` variable.

P.S. I dont want to save **drawable image to SD card to get file** before uploading as I want to avoid the permission issue.

Is there any way to upload an image directly to server without saving it inside SD card?

Comment: Save it to internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`).

Comment: it doesn't need any permission? @CommonsWare

Comment: No, you do not need any permissions to use internal storage.